# How to improve JPA Query performance and response time on multiple Join tables and conditions

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am very fresh java beginner and I am trying to implement possibility to review documents. User, who belongs to a certain group can review documents of particular types that are assigned to that group's review document types. User can not review own documents. When user belongs to many groups that can review many document types, sometimes I get about 1500~ documents that meet query condition. I tried paging, but still there are some visible latency in front page. When I fetch all documents (~1500) it takes about 3000+ ms. I am not sure if it is a lot or not. My JPA query is below.

```
    @Query("SELECT d FROM Document d WHERE d.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT d.id FROM Document d" +
        " JOIN d.documentType dt" +
        " JOIN dt.reviewUserGroups rug" +
        " JOIN rug.users u WHERE u.username = :username" +
        " AND d.documentState = it.akademija.wizards.enums.DocumentState.SUBMITTED" +
        " AND u <> d.author" +
        " AND (lower(CONCAT(d.author.firstname, ' ', d.author.lastname)) like %:searchFor% " +
        " OR lower(d.title) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.description) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(d.id) like %:searchFor%" +
        " OR lower(dt.title) like %:searchFor%))")
    Page<Document> getDocumentsForReview(@Param(value = "username") String username,
                                     @Param(value = "searchFor") String searchFor,
                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Please let me know what is the best way to improve performance, because I have some feeling that this type of search using "like" multiple times in query and joining through many Entities is not the right one.

Comment: You have to use indexes, btree for equals, and fulltext for likes.

Comment: Can you share the database definition in order to analyze if you're using proper indexes?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by database definition. At the moment I have not indexed anything. Hibernate creates table automatically on start up. I did not put any indexing information in entities and it would be great if you can share some documentation or tutorial how to properly index fields in entities with multiple joins (as per query provided). I am not using entity manger, just JPARepository implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fulltext search instead of `like`. Create Fulltext index  for that, see http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=fulltext&search=fulltext#fulltext